# MongoDB using Filter to get N number of most recent Document

Tags: regex, mongodb

I want to query last 3 documents from my Mongodb with filter. in the database i am receiving 300 documents in every 15 minutes , right now in my database i have almost 10,000 Documents, in each 300 Documents i have one string field contains **SYSTEM_000_00_SAVING**

**Example**
This is how my Database look like

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a81986d7aee9536681af520"),
"Data" : "02-02-2017 00:17:22 SYSTEM_000_00_SAVING "
 }

 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5a81986d7aee9536681af521"),
"Data" : "02-02-2017 00:17:22 SyTime_000_09_00:00 "
 }

{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a81986d7aee9536681af522"),
"Data" : "02-02-2017 00:17:22 DPMPow_P01_04_   0.00 "
}
```

.....so and so after 289 or 300 again i will receive

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a81990c7aee9536681cda23"),
"Data" : "03-03-2017 23:58:11 SYSTEM_000_00_SAVING "
 }

 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5a81990c7aee9536681cda22"),
"Data" : "03-03-2017 23:58:11 AHOnff_028_00_0 "
}

{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a81990c7aee9536681cda21"),
"Data" : "03-03-2017 23:58:10 AHTime_027_09_22:53 "
}
```

this is what i have tried with -1 and 1

```
 db.getCollection('ROB_CAP').find({"Data" : /.*SAVING.*/}).sort({_id:1}).limit(3)
```

query above is working but it showing me incorrect result .

**Query Result sort({_id:1})**

```
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5a81986d7aee9536681af520"),
"Data" : "02-02-2017 00:17:22 SYSTEM_000_00_SAVING "
 }


 {
 "_id" : ObjectId("5a81986d7aee9536681af667"),
"Data" : "02-02-2017 00:32:23 SYSTEM_000_00_SAVING "
 }

 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5a81986e7aee9536681af7ae"),
"Data" : "02-02-2017 00:47:24 SYSTEM_000_00_SAVING "
}
```

**Query Result sort({_id:-1})**

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a81987a7aee9536681b6901"),
"Data" : "02-02-2017 23:48:56 SYSTEM_000_00_SAVING "
}
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5a81987a7aee9536681b67b3"),
"Data" : "02-02-2017 23:33:55 SYSTEM_000_00_SAVING "
 }

 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5a81987a7aee9536681b666c"),
"Data" : "02-02-2017 23:18:54 SYSTEM_000_00_SAVING "
 }
```

in the Database, i have data from 02-02-2017  to until 10-10-2017 , i suppose to receive last 3 documents from 10-10-2017 with above query but its showing data from start Date.

ask me for further info if you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake Query works fine as i expected. 
actually the problem was in the data , i deleted the collection and uploaded data again, it worked.

```
  db.getCollection('ROB_CAP').find({"Data" : /.*SAVING.*}).sort({_id:1}).limit(3)
```

in Future if someone wants to  query with MongoDB using Filter to get N number of most recent Document . feel free to test this query it will work .. 
i have tested this query on Robo3T -1.1